# Domatic lights puzzle - an introduction

Tags: grid-deduction

Rules:

- Each white hex must contain either a red, green or blue light bulb.
- Light bulbs of the same color cannot be in neighboring hexes.
- Each white hex must be lit by all three colors of light (including those that already have light bulbs in them).
- Light travels away from light bulbs in six rays, one each through the six sides of the hex.
- Light continues in a straight line until it is blocked by a black wall hex.

[image: Domatic lights puzzle]

Comment: I'm still feeling out the rules and trying to see whether or not this type of puzzle can be interestingly difficult.

Comment: 1) "Each white hex must contain either a red, green or blue light bulb" vs 2) "including those that already have light bulbs in them". According to (1) ALL of them have a light bulb in them. What are we excluding?

Comment: "Those that already have light bulbs in them" being those that start with light bulbs. That's to clarify that you also need to add the other two colors to hexes that aren't empty to start with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solution:

> [image]

---

This was fun! Here’s how I solved it:

You can get to here pretty straightforwardly:

> [image]

From here, bottom left must be green and the top can also be filled in:

> [image]

The rightmost must be blue, making two below it green. From there the colours need to alternate, with the bottom being red. We get the solution:

> [image]

Comment: Corrected the slightly incorrect answer. Now it’s completely solvable with logic, just my 2 AM brain making a silly error :)